# Unusual laptop booting

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I have an toshiba sattelite c50.
It won't boot any longer from any bootable device (hdd, (intern, extern)cdrom, usb)

All the bootable devices are MBR partitioned and work on other laptop/pc.

situation before problem occurs:

- (bios settings)
  See images for my bios settings>

security tab https://ibb.co/jFvPcm

power mngmnt tab https://ibb.co/jSe6q6

advanced tab https://ibb.co/bDu6q6

advanced sub menu https://ibb.co/kvfeA6

Mainoverview (seems to be oke, just an overview)

Boot menu in bios (recognizes all devices internal, external)

Boot menu retrieved after hitting F12 (while booting) is oke, can boot from any device.

- (hardware)

Hdd with xen hypervisor for test purposes (running 2 fedoras)
Perfect booting without problems.

Till now (yesterday):
i wanted to boot as normally my laptop but now he doesn't boot but give me an message "No bootable device -- Please restart the system".

1. New RAM memory tried from another laptop and reverse -> retrieve same error
2. i try an live linux usb and an internal, external cdrom to boot but --> same error
3. To see if any hardware is broken i pulled out any hdd, cdrom and boot only from usb but --> same error.
4. hdd and usb tested on another laptop an pc  --> boot perfect, devices oke.
5. Battery and bios battery pulled out for a whole night, i resetted bios settings via bios interface but --> same error.

All the hardware is well recognized in the bios.

Boot menu retrieved after hitting F12 (while booting) displays the boot-devices menu and when i entered an boot device the 'boot menu page' just refresh and do not boot.

I dont know what to do with it anymore.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The `Boot Mode` setting in "advanced sub menu" of your BIOS settings indicates the system is configured for `CSM Boot`, which is what you want when booting from MBR-bootable devices.

However, only the top part of the "security tab" is visible, and it might contain an important setting: if Secure Boot is enabled, the `CSM Boot` might be impossible, as Secure Boot requires UEFI-style boot procedures.

The help text for `Boot Mode` indicates that setting won't be reset if the BIOS settings are reset to default settings. But if the Secure Boot setting does not have similar protection, it might have caused a combination of settings that makes booting impossible. That would ultimately be a mistake on the BIOS programmer's part.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. My security page only contains these two functions displayed on the picture. (It seems to be secure boot not possible here. (The pic is from internet but 100% same settings as mine bios)

Comment: You might try temporarily switching `Boot Mode` to UEFI, just in case it brings the Secure Boot-related settings visible in the BIOS menus. If it does, *first* disable Secure Boot, *only then* restore the `Boot Mode` to CSM.

Comment: Do you know if the chances are real to be it a virus?

Comment: I will give it a try. I shall feedback you.

Comment: If it was a virus, it would be quite a self-defeating one: preventing a system from booting would also stop the virus from spreading. I guess it would be possible, but I think a virus behaving like this is not very probable. Could you describe how the `Boot` tab of the BIOS settings looks like?

Comment: https://ibb.co/h357DR bios boot menu
https://ibb.co/kQKOnm bios main overview
https://ibb.co/dQsXf6 security
https://ibb.co/fp8506 F12 boot menu

Comment: On the `Main` tab, it says `None` on the "HDD/SSD" line. Can you change it to anything else, like `Autodetect` or similar? Usually `None` here means "don't bother trying to detect a disk, just assume there isn't one". If it is just an indication, not a changeable field, then I'm afraid there might be a hardware issue - and since you have already tested the disk in another laptop, it seems likely that the damage is in the laptop's motherboard.

Comment: Of course it could also be simply that the disk is not seated in its connector firmly enough, and so there is no good electrical connection between the laptop and the disk.

Comment: I cant change the 'None' field.

Comment: And the connection between hdd en laptop is oke. Usb ports are ok because it recognized usb devices. The strange is that bios post give no errors and i get into the step to choose where to search for mbr and bios wil refuse to read from any device.

Comment: As the `Main` tab says `None`on the "HDD/SSD" line, it means the BIOS is not detecting the HDD at all. If the HDD was detected, its model should be shown on the F12 boot menu, similar to "KingstonDataTraveler 3.0" on the USB line.

Comment: Yes, sorry i had not described what the situation now is. Only the usb is connected with a live linux that works on another pc and laptop and worked before on this 'broken laptop'.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas then.

Comment: Its an ssd drive but i can test it with an older hdd and i can use an external power source for to be sure enough power is delivered.

Comment: I also was thinking overheating hardware with xen hypervisor but more likely not i think because the laptop dont fell out by itself and was not extremely hot. Temperature like always +-2years

Comment: Secure boot was off. Now my laptop even display nothing. I think i put it in trash.